# Significance of cut-off frequency in a low-pass filter

Tags: transfer-function, low-pass, cutoff-frequency

My question is: why do we choose cut-off frequency to satisfy that the magnitude of transfer function \$ H(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \$?

Therefore I am not asking how cut-off frequency is calculated as \$ \sqrt{\frac{R}{L}}\$, but I am asking why it is chosen that way.

I know I sound a bit confusing but it is because I am confused. Thanks in advance

Comment: To add more confusion: This is really only a _convention_. You can pick other magnitudes to call the cut-off point. -3 dB is pretty useful, though.

Comment: @pipe huh, I needed this answer to satisfy myself, then my next question is: In what way it is useful so that it is chosen as cut-off frequency?

Comment: I don't think I can answer that better than how Bimpelrekkie did. Since there is never a _hard_ limit in a physically realizable filter, it makes sense to put it where half the power is on one side and half on the other.

Answer (score 13):

*H(w) =1/ (square root of 2)* That sounds a bit confusing, we usually refer to the cutoff point as the -3 dB point.

That is the same though, -3 dB is **half** the power.

Let me explain: take your \$H(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\$

That means that at that \$\omega\$ the **voltage** is divided by \$\sqrt2\$, if this voltage is applied across a (load) resistor at the output of the filter then the current through that same load resistor will also be divided by \$\sqrt2\$.

What does that mean for the **Power**?

I means that the power is **halved**.

On a dB Power scale that means -3 dB

Using that "half of the power" as a reference point is useful because if we divide a wideband signal into a low frequency part and a high frequency part then we can do that using a low pass filter and a highpass filter with the same cutoff frequency. At that cutoff frequency half of the power ends up at the output of the lowpass filter and the other half ends up at the output of the highpass filter.

Comment: So "*why do we choose cut-off frequency to satisfy that the magnitude of transfer function H(w) =1/ (square root of 2)?*" is answered with "*I means that the power is halved.*". And... why do we choose when the power has been halved? Maybe this isn't OP's question, but this will be his/hers next question.

Comment: I added an explanation for that.

Comment: And that deserves a +1 from me.

Comment: Doesn't this assume unit gain at DC? Wouldn't $$H(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} H (0)$$ be better?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Only for a **Low pass filter**. Consider a high pass filter which will often **completely block** DC. More accurately the -3dB point is at a frequency relative to the **passband**.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Sure, but why assume that the passband has unit gain?

Comment: The gain in the passband doesn't have to be 1 (unity), it can still be anything you like. The answer states \$H(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\$ which comes from the question, more accurate would be: \$H(\omega) = H(\omega_{passband})/ \sqrt2\$